# insert into new table Query with select from old table

Tags: php, sqlsrv

i have table in sql with name employee_detail and it has 6 columns,
(id, EMpid, name , Dept, Role, and Manager ) from where i retried detail on front 
 end datatable (using PHP 7.0.27) besides that i have 3 more columns in which i m asking for inputs from User for ( Leave_from-datepicker, Leave_to-datepicker, and LEave_type-listbox using select and option) and submit button at the end of the datatable if i click on submit button, the data to be inserted into sql server, but it is not happening,

here is what i have tried,

```
<?php
require('connection.php');
$startdate = strtotime($_POST["Leave_from"]);
$enddate = strtotime($_POST["Leave_to"]);
$sdate = date('Y-m-d',$startdate);
$edate = date('Y-m-d',$enddate);
$datediff = $sdate - $edate;
$countdays = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));

$query = "INSERT INTO leave_log(ID, Employee_ID, Name, Dept, Manager, Leave_from, Leave_to, Leave_type) 
VALUES 
(
  '".$_POST["ID"]."',
  '".$_POST["Empployee_id"]."',
  '".$_POST["Name"]."',
  '".$_POST["Dept"]."',
  '".$_SESSION["Manager"]."',
  '" . $sdate . "',
  '" . $edate . "',
  '".$_POST["Leave_type"]."';
echo $query;
?>
```

what will be the Exact insert query to insert this records into sql server

Comment: Do you have an error ? A message to show us ?

Comment: after clicking on submit button nothing happen, no error, nor insert into sql table

Comment: Could you post the result of `echo $query;`and the type of each fields of your DB ?

Comment: i get nothing Bro, if i click on submit button nothing happen's and types for each fields are ID - int, Employee_id - int , name-text, dept-text,manager-text, leave_from - date, leave_to-date, Leave_type-text

Comment: If you get nothing for your `echo $query;` it's because your code stop before. Try to not put quote for field that are not typed text in your database schema